# Server will not run: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook

Tags: java, maven, apache-poi

I am trying to run my web application with a tomcat 9 server but i keep getting the same error:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
I also tried adding poi ooxml back, did not work. Also tried only with the poi, did not work.

What am i doing wrong?

Imports:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
```

Pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>houseoftyping</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- javax-servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- mysql connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20200518</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure you packaged all the dependencies into the .war or WEB-INF/libs folder? Your pom doesn't seem to be building a .war but a .jar file - which in itself will not contain any of the dependencies

Comment: How can i build my project into a war?

Comment: <packaging>war</packaging> plus maybe you need the maven war plugin - https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

When developing webapps, it's important that all the dependencies are visible to the webapp classloader (by placing them in WEB-INF/lib). Easiest way to accomplish this would be for maven to create a .war instead of a .jar.

Your pom.xml would then look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com</groupId>
  <artifactId>houseoftyping</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    [as before]
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```